# What is causing my ~/Library folder to be come visible again?

Tags: macos

At some point after Lion system updates, my ~/Library folder becomes visible again, in seemingly spontaneous fashion. If I make it invisible, it will become visible yet again. What could be causing this? Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: My guess would be a 3rd party app doing this. You would expect the opposite though, as it is hidden by default in Lion, and I have experienced it being hidden again after explicitely unhiding it (probably through software updates).

Comment: Probably a third-party installer, right? Wouldn't the app require administrator privileges to change the visibility parameter?

Comment: Well at least it doesn't require an administrator password when setting it from the terminal, so I'm not sure an app would need extra privileges to do so.

Comment: An administrator password is not required for making changes to a user's own files or preferences, unless the user is attempting to rename or remove a file needed by OS X. Changing visibility only changes flags on the file, but does not render the file or folder inaccessible to the OS, thus, doesn't require an administrator's permission.

Answer (score 1):

It is VueScan. The developer (who otherwise is great) does annoying things like this, or adding the app's icon to the Dock without making them a preference.